# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:~/test

Tags: java, maven, jar, сборка, h2

Хочу подключить база данных H2. При запуске в Intellij IDEA все работает. Но если собрать проект в Maven и запустить .jar файл через командную строку то выбрасывает ошибку.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:h2:~/test

Если добавить `Class.forName ("org.h2.Driver");`, то выбрасывает

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver.

Опять же в IDEA все работает. 
Пробовал менять версии H2 на более старые, не помогает.
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

```
private static Connection conn;
private static Statement statement;

public static void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName ("org.h2.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>IV</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<name>IV</name>
<description>V</description>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>start.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>start.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить следующие записи в `pom.xml`

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>my.package.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>my.package.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
```

Создаете jar файл следующей командой `mvn compile assembly:single`

Comment: Спасибо  Артем, сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять версию драйвера

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.121</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Безрезультатно.

Comment: Ну надо конечно прописать путь к драйверу на пути классов, или же указать его в манифесте.